# Excel formula for multiple less than and greater than conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Display the population density status as follows:

```
Density            Status

Below 1000         Very Small

Below 2000         Small

Below 3000         Medium 

Below 6000         Large

At 6000 or Above   Very Large
```

Workings:

New York City has a population density of 4100 (this is in cell `A1`)

I thought it may be possible to write an Excel formula like this:

`=IFS(A1>=6000, "Very Large", 3000 < A1 < 6000, "Large", 2000 < A1 < 3000, "Medium", 1000 < A1 < 2000, "Small", 1000 < A1, "Very Small")`

But this does not work. Any help will be appreciated to write a formula to return the `Status` for a given population entered in e.g. `A1`.

Comment: Excel doesn't support chained comparisons like `3000 < A1 < 6000`.

Comment: `1` "Ifs" is not a function in my version of Excel. `2.`  You can't have two part logical tests (e.g. `1000<a1<2000`  should be `AND(1000<a1, a1<2000)`)

Comment: @user2357112 Darn it. I'm too use to C++ then :p

Comment: @TillermansTea: C++ doesn't support that either; if you were doing it in C++, you were getting silently wrong behavior. The only language I know of that supports that syntax with the semantics you're thinking of is Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula:

```
IFS(A1>=6000, "Very Large", 3000 < A1 < 6000, "Large", 2000 < A1 < 3000, "Medium", 1000 < A1 < 2000, "Small", 1000 < A1, "Very Small")
```

1. `Ifs(` is not a function in my version of Excel.  Nested if statements work for me:  `=if(test1, Value_If_True, if(test2.....` etc.   Can't wait till my employer gets with the program!
2. You can't have two part logical tests (e.g. `1000<a1<2000`  should be `AND(1000<a1, a1<2000)`)
3. It isn't necessary to repeat these tests like this.  If A1 is greater than or equal to 6000, then the first test evaluates true.  If it doesn't evaluate true, you needn't repeat the test.
4. Syntax aside, your logic doesn't quite match your table anyways.  (`1000<A1, 
   "Very Small"` should have been `1000 >A1, "Very Small"`)

If I were doing this with if statements:

```
=IF( A1 >=6000, "Very Large", if(A1>=3000  , "Large", if(A1>=2000 , "Medium", if(A1>=1000, "Small",  "Very Small")
```

In your version of excel:

```
=IFS( A1 >=6000, "Very Large", A1>=3000  , "Large", A1>=2000 , "Medium", A1>=1000, "Small",  "Very Small")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do things like:

LowLimit < x < HighLimit

Try instead something like...

AND(X>LowLimit,X

AND() will return true/false as per binary AND operator.

Comment: Once you have failed `high limit<=X`, there is no need to repeat that portion of the test `AND(Low Limit <X, X<High Limit)`

Answer (score 0):

You can link a bunch of IFs together like this:

```
=IF(A6>=6000,"Very Large",IF(A6>=3000,"Large",IF(A6>=2000,"Medium",IF(A6>=1000,"Small","Very Small"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=LOOKUP(A1/1000,{0,1,2,3,6;"Very Small","Small","Medium","Large","Very Large"})
```

If the value can be negative, you can replace `0` with the lowest possible number or `-1E+307`(-10^307)

The rectangular array part `{;}` can be replaced with range or named range that contains the values.